# Reactjs frontend deployed in AWS cloudfront

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am learning AWS by doing. I have deployed Reactjs fronted in AWS cloudfront.It has also backend done by springboot backend which is deployed in AWS ECS. All deployment was successful. Here is the link of cloudfront:-

https://d2qwk54jp0dy3h.cloudfront.net/

That is link I clik I got error:-

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DHQ9ZWJYT5RDMMYF</RequestId>
<HostId>G4Zp/SY7wb7FxwyjlWHcp+uuEHY4XwissxtsixTgkYJzEVibXyVIJZPf6d9Kz6cBBvOTIlSm1Ic=</HostId>
```

What is wrong and how to solve?

Comment: Looks like some permission issue. You need to give specific role iam role.

Comment: did you check cors? Check cors cloudfront OAI policy